# what is the following error indicate in react native "Error: Expected value to be a string, got a number, js engine: hermes"

Tags: string, react-native, numbers

In react native I have  done a project in realm and i had use a number in string in  "" also i had stored that in string but this error occured "Error: Expected value to be a string, got a number, js engine: hermes"

I need the solution of this error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.